# Solving a cubic equation system

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I got a cubic equation system that contains 3 cubic equations with 3 variables.

I want to find the number of solutions and the solutions themselves (as a numerical approximation).

Do you know good algorithms and/or theorems that apply to this problem?

Comment: Like this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418217/visualise-3-simultaneous-cubic-equations or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399210/solving-3-simultaneous-cubic-equations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use the Buchberger algorithm, to obtain algebraic solutions.
Since I do not know your equations, we may consider the following cubic equations
$$
(x_1+x_2)^3=x_3
$$

$$
(x_2+x_3)^3=x_1
$$

$$
(x_3+x_1)^3=x_2
$$

Then Buchberger's algorithm yields the solutions, e.g., $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ means  $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(0,0,0)$, and $\{x_1,x_2 + x_3,x_3^2 + 1\}$ denotes the
solutions $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with $x_1=0$, $x_3=-x_2$ and $x_3^2=-1$ (obviously only possible over the complex numbers). We have $\{x_1 - 8x_3^3,
x_2 - x_3, 64x_3^6 + 32x_3^4 + 7x_3^2 + 1\}$, etc.
It is possible to list all solutions in this way.